# ADD command not working Docker

Tags: bash, laravel, docker

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.16 
MAINTAINER Raheel <raheelwp@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 curl git

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python-software-properties
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install php5 php5-cli php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-xdebug php5-json
RUN apt-get clean
RUN php5enmod mcrypt
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

ADD /home/raheel/code/laravel-app /var/www/laravel-app

EXPOSE 80

COPY setup-laravel.sh /var/www/laravel-app/setup-laravel.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/var/www/laravel-app/setup-laravel.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/laravel-app/setup-laravel.sh"]
```

I created the above Dockerfile to run laravel application.

Then i ran `docker build -t raheelwp/laravel-app .` command and it created the image without name. Then i ran `docker tag imageid raheelwp/laravel-app` . After this when i check `docker images` it shows my image with name.

So far so good. But when i run `docker run -t raheelwp/laravel-app` and then login into container by `docker exec -it containerid bash` and do the ls on `/var/www` directory there is no laravel-app folder present there.

I am new to docker and this is my first ever docker file. I would be very thankful to you to please guide me why i am having this problem and how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: There must be something wrong with image building, you should see the image name in the image list. Do you see any errors when building the image?

Comment: Yes. Actually that was fixed. The problem was the ADD command work in current context. so adding `/home/...` didn't work. Rather i mapped `. /path_to_map`